# Set data to NavigationView menu items

Tags: android, android-menu, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

If I add a custom item to my `NavigationView` menu, like so:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

MenuItem item = menu.add("Item 1");
```

How can I set data to the item (like an object) so that, when it's clicked/selected, I can pass that data to the activity it opens?

Answer (score 2):

You can't set/add data to menu items. By looking at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) of `add()` method, it can be seen that you can set:

> **groupId** - int: The group identifier that this item should be part of. This can be used to define groups of items for batch state changes. Normally use NONE if an item should not be in a group.
>
> **itemId** - int: Unique item ID. Use NONE if you do not need a unique ID.
>
> **order** - int: The order for the item. Use NONE if you do not care about the order. See getOrder().
>
> **title** - CharSequence: The text to display for the item.

Therefore:

You need to set `itemId` and handle specific tasks inside `onNavigationItemSelected()`

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.id_of_menu_item_1) {

        // handle intents and passing data

    } else if (id == R.id.id_of_menu_item_2) {

        // handle intents and passing data

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I set data on the **menu item** that I can then pass on to the activity on click? For example, how can I set a `User` object on the item, and then when that item is selected, have it sent to the activity? In your example, I can only pass data when the item is selected. What I need is to be able to attach data to an item, and then, when selected, get that data and pass it to the activity.

Comment: You don't set any kind of data to menu item except its id. They can only be clicked. When it happens, they call `onNavigationItemSelected()` method. Now, you identify which menu item was clicked by reading id and handle the necessary tasks. For example, create `intent` and pass data, or do any other tasks you want

Comment: What if many of my menu items open the same activity, but need to pass on different data (objects in this case)?

Comment: Each menu item should have different ids. For this reason, you have `if` statement in `onNavigationItemSelected` method. Based on the id of clicked menu item you pass required data to any activity

Comment: @user7556225 Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense for me. MenuItem class only holds attributes relative to menu item. You cannot put other objects inside MenuItem instance. Take a look about MenuItem class:

[MenuItem class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html)

You can use repository pattern to get needed data on new activity or load object on current activity and pass to new activity using intent, just create a `Bundle` and put your serializable or parcelable object on it. You can make this when you handle `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`